# Could not create project template with version 5.0.0

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I use maven command line to create project template with version 5 but failed with the following error.

It looks like spring-boot3-5.0.0.jar does not exist in maven repository. Please check.

```
C:\Workspace\Projects>mvn archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.sdk.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot3" "-DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.889 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-12-15T21:24:14+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.sap.cloud.sdk.archetypes:spring-boot3:RELEASE) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the release of the archetype, we plan to fix it by next week for version `5.1.0`.
I will keep you informed.

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Will it affect upgrading from version 4 to version 5 due to this issue?

Comment: No, this is only for new projects being generated.

Comment: The release of `5.1.0` fixed the `spring-boot3` archetype.
You can generate it again:
`mvn  archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.sdk.archetypes" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot3" "-DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE"`